# "What does this entire sentence mean?" Questions

Tags: discussion, questions

In my opinion, questions which quote an entire sentence or paragraph and then say "what does this mean?" are simply another variant of proofreading; I want to see a specific point of concern identified, or you're asking us to take a shot in the dark and/or explain *everything* about the sentence, which simply isn't feasible. How can we explain if we don't know what you don't understand?

Following on this idea, I fully intended to close [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19422/what-does-this-complicated-and-convoluted-sentence-mean). That is, until I saw if had four (four!) separate answers. Now we've discussed in the past that sometimes people answer questions even though they know they should be closed...  But I find it hard to believe that four people would do that on the same question. Which the leads me to believe that others think it should remain open, and I should reconsider my position. So, can anyone in favor of it remaining open please state your case? I don't find questions like these at all constructive, but I'm open to hearing other opinions. (I have to admit I do hope it will start gaining close votes without mod intervention soon, though.)

Comment: I mostly agree, though I don't think this is even remotely related to proofreading - it's more "Help! I'm totally baffled!" I might have voted to close it eventually, if it reached the closure queue when I was online; but right now I feel nxx' answer demonstrates a very useful approach to analyzing complex sentences like this - so I refrain, to give that answer more opportunity to earn upvotes.

Comment: Guilty as charged. I didn't really think about it at the time I answered, but the request for help seemed genuine and I thought I had an approach that might be helpful. The OP's "complicated and convoluted" seemed to be an effort to identify a problem and I do tend to give the benefit of the doubt sometimes that the source of confusion is simply difficult to identify and express. That said, I have no particular reason to argue that it should be left open. What to do with genuine requests for help but difficulty explaining the issue precisely is another question.

Comment: @nxx I don't in any way mean anything negative towards those who answered, so I apologize if it came across that way. I think what I was meaning to say was "This seems like a really clear-cut case to me, so since four people answered is there something I'm missing? Because four answers is a lot." If it helps, if I had closed, I'd have left a comment for the OP suggesting they edit to explain what they did understand and at what point they got lost, and I'd have reopened if they did so.

Comment: @WendiKidd It's all good. I got what you meant. I've definitely thought "is there something I'm missing?" at times too. Would it not be useful to question the OP or even close the question anyway?